# Algebraic definition or construction of real numbers

Tags: definition

Is there any algebraic definition or construction of real numbers ?

If not, why ?

Comment: What does "algebraic" mean in this context?

Comment: Do [dedekind cuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) count?

Comment: You can construct them as the quotient ring $C/M$ where $C$ is the ring of Cauchy sequences in ${\mathbf Q}$ (with pointwise addition and multiplication) and $M$ is the maximal ideal of null sequences (sequences in $\mathbf Q$ that tend to $0$).

Comment: Without using Dedekind axiom, Cauchy sequences, upper bound axiom or equivalents. I don't know how to explain well. My algebra book says :<< the construction of the reals has not an algebraic nature, so refer to a calculus textbook >>.

Comment: What "algebra book" are you reading?  Construction of the real numbers would not be covered in most calculus textbooks either.

Comment: Here's a suggestion I'm not sure about (feedback required): $\Bbb C/\Bbb Q$ is the algebraic closure. However, it isn't ordered. Could it be that $\Bbb R$ is a (the?) maximal ordered field $\mathbb{Q}\subset F\subset\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You might look up "real closed field"

Comment: I mean Mathematical analysis book

Answer (score 19):

There is a strong sense in which the answer is **no**:

It's an informal concept, but we might reasonably say that an "algebraic" construction of the reals is one which only refers to algebraic operations - e.g., polynomials and their roots - and does not talk about more complicated things, such as arbitrary sets of rational numbers (e.g., Dedekind cuts and Cauchy sequences). In particular, we might ask for this construction to take place in **first-order logic**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic.

This, we can prove, is impossible. Here's one way to say this:

> There is a countable field $F$, with $\mathbb{Q}\subset F\subset\mathbb{R}$, such that $F$ satisfies every first-order sentence in the language of fields which is true in $\mathbb{R}$.

This is a direct consequence of the **Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem**, and it is very powerful and flexible; for instance, we can replace "the language of fields" with "the language of fields with exponentiation, $\sin$, $\cos$, and the Gamma function," and we could still find such an $F$. So no algebraic construction is guaranteed to get *all* of $\mathbb{R}$.