# Axioms of Real Numbers using Groups

Tags: real-numbers

Some texts define the field of real numbers as a set $\mathbb{R}$, on which there are two operations defined (called Addition $+$ and Multiplication $\cdot$, respectively), such that:

1. $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is an abelian group with neutral element $0$;
2. $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is an abelian group with neutral element $1$;
3. For all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ we have (distributivity laws):
   \begin{align*}
   a\cdot (b+c)=(a\cdot b)+(a\cdot c)
   \\
   (b+c)\cdot a=(b\cdot a)+(c\cdot a).
   \end{align*}

At first this seemed to me like a nice way to define the real numbers. However, on second thought, from 2. we have associativity, commutativity, and the existence of a neutral element for multiplication for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ instead of for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Did I miss something or is the short definition given above indeed incomplete?

Comment: Note that $0\cdot a=0$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$.  Also, this is the definition of a field, but there are fields besides $\mathbb R$, such as $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb C$

Comment: Why would it be?

Comment: Why would $0\cdot a=0$?  See the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote cannot possibly a *definition* of $\Bbb R$ since it applies to *every* field.

Anyway, nothing is missing. First of all, note that you always have $a.0=0$, since\begin{align}0&=a.0-a.0\\&=a.(0+0)-a.0\\&=(a.0+a.0)-a.0\\&=a.0+(a.0-a.0)\\&=a.0+0\\&=a.0.\end{align}For the same reason, $0.a=0$. So,   commutativity holds when one of the elements is $0$. Since $1.0=0.1=0$, $1$ is still the neutral element. And if one of the numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ is $0$, $(ab)c=a(bc)$ since both numbers are equal to $0$.

Comment: Right, I was only talking about the field axioms, actually. Well, if the only axiom we state for multiplication is that $(R\0,\cdot)$ is an abelian group, then to prove $0\cdot a=0$ we have to use the laws of distributivity as noticed in your answer. But all that gives us is $a\cdot 0=a\cdot (0+0)=a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0$, not $a\cdot 0=0$... unless I missed something here.

I can follow your arguments after establishing $0\cdot a=0$ though.

Comment: I have expanded my justification of the fact that $a.0=0$. What do you think now?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the axioms given do determine how $0$ multiplies - you can show that we must have $0\times r=r\times 0=0$ for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$. This is a good exercise (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483716/in-a-ring-how-do-we-prove-that-a-0-0)).

That said, this description is **still very far from complete**. For example, both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ satisfy all those rules as well, despite being very different from $\mathbb{R}$. At the very least we should add further axioms which ensure *[real closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field)*.

(In fact there is a precise sense in which there is *no* "simple definition" of $\mathbb{R}$, although that's a bit technical - this is discussed in various places at this site, e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652312/algebraic-definition-or-construction-of-real-numbers) or [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761716/is-there-an-algebraic-way-to-construct-the-reals).)